# WP-admin directory direct function

Tags: wordpress

I wanna include a file form `wp-admin/includes` directory.
Like this:

`require_once(ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );`

But this code doesn't work:
`require_once(admin_url('/includes/class-wp-list-table.php'));`

I need to call admin directory directly instead of `/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php`. Something  like this

`require_once(WP_ADMIN.'/includes/class-wp-list-table.php')` ;
Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this function in your `function.php` file and call it when you want to include your file.

```
function my_plugin_get_admin_path() {
    // Replace the site base URL with the absolute path to its installation directory. 
    $admin_path = str_replace( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/', ABSPATH, get_admin_url() );

    // Make it filterable, so other plugins can hook into it.
    $admin_path = apply_filters( 'my_plugin_get_admin_path', $admin_path );
    return $admin_path;
}
```

It should work.